# returning a pointer to a struct which has a char ** pointer-to-pointer in it

Tags: c, pointers, struct, return-type

I just cant understand, how am I supposed to return a struct which contains a double pointer in it.... when ever i try it prints correct values in same function... but prints garbage values when i print after i return it to main...

```
struct arguments{
char **argv;
int argc;
};
```

this is the struct.

```
struct arguments * shell_make_argu(char *line)
{
   struct arguments *data=malloc(sizeof(struct arguments));
   int bufsize = word_BUFSIZE , i;
   data->argc = 0;
   data->argv = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
   char *word;

  if (!data->argv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "shell memory allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

word = strtok(line, word_separater);
while (word != NULL) {
    data->argv[data->argc] = word;
    data->argc++;

    if (data->argc >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += word_BUFSIZE;
      data->argv = realloc(data->argv, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
      if (!data->argv) {
        fprintf(stderr, "shell memory allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    word = strtok(NULL, word_separater);
}
data->argv[data->argc] = NULL;
for(i=0;i<data->argc;i++)
    printf("Command was: %s\n",data->argv[i]);
return data;
}
```

and this is how i am receiving the struct in main....

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
struct arguments *data = malloc(sizeof(struct arguments));
char *line;
int status = 1 , i;
do {
    printf("T_Shell>> ");                           
    line = shell_take_input();                     
    if(line != '\0' && strcmp(line,"found ctrl_D") != 0){
        data = shell_make_argu(line);
        free(line);
        for(i=0;i<data->argc;i++)
            printf("Command was: %s\n",data->argv[i]);
        shell_execute_comand(data->argc,data->argv);
    }
    else if(line == '\0')
        printf("\n");
    else
        break;
 } while (status);
 system("clear");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C++ code, more like C code. C code may double as valid C++ code, but it seldom is *good* C++ code. If you are using C++, you might as well use the good bits. If you are using C, please don't use the C++ question tag.

Comment: I'd like to add that you should generally read the descriptions of tags before applying them. Look at the description of the "double" tag for example, is that what you mean?

Comment: The funny part is that this was originally tagged C#, and I guess a C# tag subscriber retagged it to C++, rather than C.  I fixed the tags and question slightly, but didn't spend much time on a low-quality question like this.  (OP: this is larger than a minimal complete verifiable example.  Chop out everything that doesn't have to be there to still see a problem, and you might realize what you're doing wrong along the way.  I find that half the time when I start writing a good bug report, I end up finding a mistake in something I was doing myself.)

Comment: Also, the question originally said "returning a struct", rather than returning a pointer to a struct.  You *can* return a struct by value (which in the ABI for most architectures, turns into storing through a caller-provided pointer.)  Not that it would make the difference here.

Answer (score 1):

You did `free` to `line` before printing `data->argv` in `main` function, which is bad because each elements of `data->argv` are pointing to the buffer pointed by `line`.

Do the `free` after calling `shell_execute_comand`, or allocate new memory and copy the strings returned by `strtok` instead of assigning `strtok`'s return value directly to the elements of `data->argv`.

Answer (score 0):

shell_make_argu() function:

```
struct arguments* shell_make_argu(char *line)
{
   struct arguments *data = malloc(sizeof(struct arguments));
   int bufsize = word_BUFSIZE , i;

   data->argc = 0;
   data->argv = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));

   char *word;

   if (!data->argv) 
   {
       fprintf(stderr, "shell memory allocation error\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   word = strtok(line, word_separater);
   while (word != NULL) 
   {
       if (data->argc == bufsize)  <-- Moved realloc at beginning of loop
       {
           bufsize += word_BUFSIZE;
           data->argv = realloc(data->argv, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
           if (!data->argv) 
           {
               fprintf(stderr, "shell memory allocation error\n");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
       }

       data->argv[data->argc] = malloc(strlen(word)+1);  <-- Added allocation of argv[argc] char pointer
       strcpy(data->argv[data->argc], word);   <-- Added storing token

       data->argc++;

       word = strtok(NULL, word_separater);
   }

   //data->argv[data->argc] = NULL;   <-- Not required, can be removed
   for(i=0;i<data->argc;i++)
       printf("Command was: %s\n",data->argv[i]);

    return data;
}
```

main() function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct arguments *data;  <-- Removed malloc, make_shell_argu() returns allocated pointer
    char *line;
    int status = 1 , i;
    do 
    {
        printf("T_Shell>> ");                           
        line = shell_take_input();                     
        if(line != NULL && strcmp(line,"found ctrl_D") != 0)  <-- Changed condition check with (line != NULL)
        {
            data = shell_make_argu(line);
            free(line);

            for(i=0;i<data->argc;i++)
                printf("Command was: %s\n",data->argv[i]);

            shell_execute_comand(data->argc,data->argv);

            for(i=0;i<data->argc;i++)  <-- Added memory releasing code
            {
                free(data->argv[i]);
            }
            free(data->argv);
            free(data);                 <-- Freeing 'data' also, make_shell_argu() will return new allocated pointer next time
        }
        else if(line == NULL)  <-- Changed condition check to (line == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            status = 0;
        }
    } while (status);

    system("clear");

    return 0;
}
```